# Generate integer number 1,2,3 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I used this query:

```
SELECT FLOOR(3 * RAND(CONVERT(varbinary, NEWID())))
```

Can someone please explain how it works? I know all the functions used, but I'm unable to link them.

Answer (score 4):

Tne `newid()` function doesn't actually generate a string, it generates a `uniqueidentifier`, also known as a "globally unique identifier", or "GUID". This is a pseudo-random value.

The `rand(@seed)` function generates a value >= 0 and < 1.

Rand doesn't generate a seed, it accepts the seed as an input parameter. The result depends on the seed. If you pass the same seed value as the input parameter, the result of `rand()` is always the same. If `rand()` is called without any seed value, SQL server itself will produce a psuedo-random seed.

Now, this probably seems confusing already. Obvious questions are:

> **If `newid()` is already pseudo-random, why do we need `rand()`?**

In the code presented in your question, `rand()` isn't actually being used to generate random values, that job is really being done by `newid()`. What `rand()` is doing is mapping the `newid()` value to a floating point value between zero and one.

> **OK then, if `rand()` with no input seed is already psuedo-random, why do we need `newid()`??**

In the specific sample code in your question, where we are only working with a single scalar value, there's actually no need. The same thing could be accomplished with:

```sql
select floor(3 * RAND() + 1)
```

However, when you are working with multiple rows of data, `rand()` doesn't get re-seeded by SQL Server for every row, it only gets seeded once. So if you do something like this:

```sql
select rand() from sys.objects
```

Then every row in the result set will have the same value.

The `newid()` function is different. SQL will generate a different `uniqueidentifier` for every single row (it sort of "has to by law" - part of the definition of a GUID is that the same GUID should never be generated twice).

So the `newid()` function is providing a psuedo-random seed value to `rand()`, and then `rand()` is mapping that to some floating point value between 0 and 1 (excluding 1).

> **What is the convert to varbinary doing?**

If an argument is passed to `rand()`, the argument has to be an integer. A `uniqueidentifier` cannot be implicitly converted to an integer. But a `uniqueidentifier` can be converted to a `varbinary`, and then the `varbinary` can be implicitly converted to an integer. If we make that conversion explicit, it looks like this:

```sql
select convert(int, convert(varbinary, newid()))
```

In your sample code, the integer conversion is being done implicitly. A `uniqueidentifier` is 16 bytes long, so it gets converted to a 16 byte `varbinary`. 12 of those bytes then get silently truncated (thrown away), because an integer is only 4 bytes long. The remaining 4 bytes are implicitly converted to the integer.

Note that this truncation could theoretically weaken the randomness of the result. People often use `checksum()` to convert to an integer rather than casting through a varbinary, because checksum will make use of all of the bytes in the GUID.

> **what is the multiplication by 3 doing?**

Since the `rand()` function returns a value between 0 and 1, but you want a value "between" 1 and 3, we have to multiply the result of `rand()`:

- Values >= 0 and < 1/3 will map to values >= 0 and < 1.
- Values >= 1/3 and < 2/3 will map to values >= 1 and < 2.
- Values >= 2/3 and < 1 will map to values >= 2 and < 3.

> **What is `floor()` doing?**

The value we have right now is some floating point value anywhere between 0 and 3 (excluding 3). But you want only the integer values 1 or 2 or 3. So we have to add 1 and shave off the decimal. This is what the `+ 1` and `floor()` are doing. You could also get rid of the `+ 1` and replace `floor()` with `ceiling()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this query:

```
select floor(3 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())))+1
```

- RAND() : returns some seed decimal number like 0.405615055347678
- newid(): returns some string: 29CADAD4-F9F5-4B79-98F0-33DE745954FC
- varbinary :  converting data from a string data type to a binary or varbinary data type of unequal length :

eg:

```
select convert(varbinary, newid())

output:
0x321A7CBE6FBACC41B1EE5BC3C5219B2C
```

Answer (score 0):

1. We can generate a random number, using the NEWID() function of SQL
   Server. Random number generated by NEWID() method will be a 32 byte
   Hexadecimal number, which is unique for your whole system.
2. The unique identifier generated by the NEWID() can be converted to
   VARBINARY using CONVERT() which in turn can be converted to an integer
   number USING FLOOR().
3. select rand()-result will be a random decimal

   The FLOOR() function returns the largest integer value that is smaller
   than or equal to a number.

   select  floor(rand()*N) —The generated number is like this: 12.0

   The number range of method: 0 to n-1, such as cast (floor (rand() *100)
   will generate any integer between 0 and 99.So here our N=3 ... we
   will be generating an integer between 0 and 3.

   SO, the  link is NEWID()>CONVERT()>RAND()>FLOOR>SELECT

[image: Screenshot of random number generation]